# any open-souce system for online ticket sale?

Tags: open-source, online, ticket-system

Hi All: 
   Is there any open source project that can be used to build a on-line ticket sales system, like: ticketmaster or eventbrite etc..? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

[CiviCRM](http://civicrm.org/) with [CiviEvent](http://civicrm.org/civievent)

http://freeseat.sourceforge.net/

Drupal with a combination of modules like [Signup](http://drupal.org/project/signup), [Event](http://drupal.org/project/event),
[Ubercart](http://drupal.org/project/uberdrupal), and [UberCart Signup](http://drupal.org/project/uc_signup)

Try searching Google for **open source ticket sales software**